# Bootstrap (with some flat UI) buttons not showing on my website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

As the title more or less says, some bootstrap buttons are not showing on my website, though they are definitely in my HTML.

Here is a codepen of the homepage of my website: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGOqER

Here is the actual website itself: http://stevenvandegraaf.nl/

Here is the actual HTML markup of the website:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <header class="header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#">Steven van de Graaf</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
                            <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section class="sub-header">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Welcome</h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    To the personal website of Steven van de Graaf
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="content background">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h2>About me</h2>
                        <p class="lead">
                            Who I am and what I do
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            As the header above says; welcome!
                            I created this website for multiple reasons.
                            The first reason is quite simple; I had already registered the domain stevenvandegraaf.nl, but was not doing anything with it thus far.
                            The second reason is that I want a place to tell others about me, my education, and my work.
                            With some time and coffee, this website was born!
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Let me first introduce myself: Hi! My name is Steven van de Graaf, and I am a 19-year-old college student from Barendrecht, The Netherlands.
                            I love the outdoors. I love hiking, kayaking, and other outdoor activities. This ties in really well with my work at a local outdoor store, as well as me being involved within Scouting.
                            Other than enjoying the outdoors, in my spare time I enjoy watching TV shows and movies, listening to a diverse range of music, and lots more.
                            My favorite color is blue. I wear a lot of dress shirts, mainly ones by McGregor. I am fully functional with 5 hours of sleep in a night. I love the peach flavour Vifit yoghurt-drink.
                            Those are some short (and fun) facts about me. Some more professional stuff can be found on their respective pages, as well as ways to get in touch with me.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="sub-footer">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Connect with me</h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    Via these media
                </p>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-2 social-btn">                      
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-embossed btn-info btn-block" href="http://www.facebook.com/steven.vdgraaf">
                        Facebook
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 social-btn">
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-embossed btn-info btn-block" href="http://nl.linkedin.com/in/stevenvandegraaf">
                        LinkedIn
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="additional-links">
                        © 2015 Steven van de Graaf. All rights reserved.
                    </div>
                </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Finally, here is the CSS:

```
body {
  color: #2C2C2C;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.231;
}

.main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

body > section,
header,
footer {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body > section,
  header,
  footer {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  color: #e74c3c;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s;
  -o-transition: 0.25s;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

a:hover {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

a:hover, button:hover, a:focus,
button:focus, a:active, button:active {
  outline: none;
}

h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h5, .h5 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h6, .h6 {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4, h5, .h5, h6, .h6 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}

p {
  font-size: 18.004px;
  line-height: 1.722169;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s;
  -o-transition: 0.25s;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #e74c3c; /* button color */
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: #e74c3c; /* button hover color */
}

.btn-info {
  background-color: #3498db; /* button color */
}

.btn-info:hover, .btn-info:focus {
  background-color: #3498db; /* button hover color */
}

img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

section * {
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.divider {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.background {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* ---------Header stuff--------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

header, .header {
  background-color: #262626; /* navbar background color */
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 73px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  background: url("../img/mobile-nav.png");
  margin-top: 8.5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle:before {
  content: none;
  }

.header .navbar {
  background-color: #262626; /* navbar background color */
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header .navbar .brand {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff; /* color of the page title */
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  height: auto;
}

.header .navbar .nav > li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header .navbar .nav > li > a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff; /* navbar link color */
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.header .navbar .nav > li:active a,
.header .navbar .nav > li.active a {
  color: #ffffff; /* active navbar element color */
}

.header .navbar .nav > li:active a:hover,
.header .navbar .nav > li.active a:hover,
.header .navbar .nav > li:active a:focus,
.header .navbar .nav > li.active a:focus,
.header .navbar .nav > li:active a.active,
.header .navbar .nav > li.active a.active {
  color: #e74c3c; /* active navbar hover element color */
}

.header .navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
.header .navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.header .navbar .nav > li > a.active {
  color: #e74c3c; /* navbar hover element color */
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* -------Sub-header stuff------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

.sub-header{
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.sub-header h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.sub-header .lead {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.sub-header .btn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* ---------Content stuff-------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

.content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.content h2 {
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.content .lead {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.content .sub-lead {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.content p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* -------Sub-footer stuff------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

.sub-footer {
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.sub-footer h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.sub-footer .lead {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.sub-footer .btn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* ---------Footer stuff--------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

footer {
  background-color: #262626;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.footer a {
  color: #ecf0f1; /* footer link color */
  font-weight: normal;
}

.footer a:hover,
.footer a:focus,
.footer a.active {
  color: #95a5a6; /* footer link hover color */
}

.footer .additional-links {
  margin-left: -25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #7f8c8d; /* footer text color */
  text-align: center;
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* --------Contact stuff--------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

.contact-field, .contact-field:focus {
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-form {
  background: none;
}

#message{
  height: 167px;
}

/* ------------------------------ */
/* -------Responsive stuff------- */
/* ------------------------------ */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .social-btn {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .sub-footer {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }

}
```

As you can see, on both there are no Facebook/LinkedIn buttons underneath the Connect with me-section near the bottom of the page. Though when I view the .html-file that is on my HDD with Google Chrome, they are most definitely there.

Why is this and how can I fix this (probably simple) problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its there in the link you speciifed ..

Comment: Your buttons are there? have you tried hitting F5 to refresh your browsers cache ? Your browser often caches things specially CSS files (styles) so you must hitF5 or Ctrl+F5 to force your browser to fetch a new version

Comment: i totally see the buttons. I opened will chrome, yandex, IE and opera

Comment: Yes, to all of you. Like I said, in the offline .html-file it totally is there when looking at it with Chrome, but when I put it on codepen or my server, they disappear. But apparantly you can see them, so then it's all good. I have refreshed, the cache and what not. Weird.